# Failure to install Sybase package on Windows 10 / Python 3.6

Tags: python, pip, sybase

I'm looking to connect to a Sybase db in PyCharm. I'm getting the following errors when installing from available packages and the terminal:

```
(venv64) C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\PyCharm\EOM_ML_201901>pip install sybase
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sybase (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sybase

(venv64) C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\PyCharm\EOM_ML_201901>pip install python-sybase
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-sybase (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-sybase
```

Has anyone succesfully installed on Win10?

Peter

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Sybase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same challenge. I resolved it by using a trial version of the Devart ODBC Driver for ASE available here https://www.devart.com/odbc/ase/download.html

After the driver is installed, it can be configured. For this, in the Control Panel open Administrative Tools and find the Data Sources (ODBC) tool. Add the Devart ODBC Driver for ASE and set up your ASE credentials.

Then from your PyCharm, connect to your ASE using the following command:

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Devart ODBC Driver for ASE}; Server=myserver; Port=myport; Database=mydatabase; User ID=myuserid; Password=mypassword; String Types=Unicode')
```